# windows Command prompt vanishes after running a python script converted to .exe using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am using python3.7

I wrote a script which takes some inputs (e.g. a=input("enter a value")

it runs smoothly if i go to its path and run it on command prompt.
I can give input also and run .
If i give wrong input it shows an error or exception(traceback)

So i converted it to .exe using pyinstaller

when i run .exe , it asks for input as expected ,it runs and vanishes , i can't see any output.
if i give a wrong input it suddenly vanishes without showing any traceback

I read many questions regarding this on stackoverflow and google , so i added an input statement at end to make program wait before exiting,

but it doesn't works in case of **wrong input** or if i use **sys.exit("test failed")** in some cases it just vanishes ,**how to resolve and keep cmd window open?**

Adding script for e.g.:

```
import sys
x = int(input("  enter a number :"))
y = int(input("  enter a number :"))
if x>100 or y > 100 :
    sys.exit("ERROR :value out of range")
z=x+y;
print(z)
input('press enter to exit')
```

if inputs are less than 100 and integer then script(.exe file) runs smoothly and i get message "press enter to exit"

but if input number greater than 100 or if i put a "string or float" in input , cmd window vanishes without display any traceback

whereas if i run py file from cmd then i get proper traceback for wrong input.

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `try-except` and `input()` function, so that when there is any error, it will wait for the user to interact.

Look at this example -

```
a = input('Please enter a number: ')

try:
    int(a) # Converts into a integer type

except ValueError as v:
    # This will run when it cannot be converted or if there is any error
    print(v) # Shows the error
    input() # Waits for user input before closing
```

For your e.g code, try this -

```
import sys

try:
    x = int(input("  enter a number :"))
    y = int(input("  enter a number :"))

except ValueError as v:
    print(v)
    input('Press any key to exit ')
    sys.exit()

if x>100 or y > 100 :
    try:
        sys.exit("ERROR :value out of range")

    except SystemExit as s:
        print(s)
        input('Press any key to exit ')
        sys.exit()
    
z=x+y

print(z)
```

You will see that the command prompt does not close immediately

Comment: Huh, I did not know that SystemExit was an Exception. TIL.

Answer (score 0):

#### You're not waiting for input.

When you run a .exe that's set up to run in the Windows console, unless you've already opened the console and if your program through that using console commands, and it was set up to just run all the way through to the end, you'll just see the window pop up and then close itself unless your program is doing something that requires user input or a lot of computational time.

This is fairly common sight when programming with languages like C# that natively run as .exes; presumably, this behaviour would also be fairly common in Python. The way to fix this is to add in a line at the end of your program to ask the user for input, so that the console will wait for the user before closing.

In your case, you mention that you have added to the end of your program; the problem is that the program isn't getting to that stage because it's hitting an exception and then exiting. You'll need to handle your exceptions and add a prompt for user input to prevent this behaviour.

Comment: what if i stop the script using sys.exit(),how to keep window open

Comment: Run the script using the Windows console (CMD) rather than just clicking on it.

Comment: This does not solve the issue - "how do I resolve it". Of course, you could use alternatives but that is different.

Comment: I want to provide a ".exe" to user , don't have option to open console

Comment: @G.ONE Then you can't keep the window open after the script closes (e.g. sys.exit()), because the window was opened by the script that has now been closed.

Answer (score 0):

Use while loop so if you gave wrong input then it will return to input again so you can give any input. and for example if you want to use only integer value then input must be convert as integer or string depend on you. example below now I think you can

```
ask = ""   #ask variable empty here because I want to use in while condition
print("YOU LOVE ME")
while ask != 'Ok Son':

    ask = input("Why? : ")

print("OK THANKS DAD")
```